# Bash Subshell Variable Command not Found

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command and interpret the results, but whatever I do I get a "command not found" error.  Here's a representative version of my code:

```
devicename="emulator-5554"
search=$(adb devices | grep -w "$devicename" | grep -w device)

until $search; do
     echo  "Waiting..."
     sleep 10
done
```

I've tried every variation that I can think of, including ...

```
search=$(adb devices | grep -w $devicename | grep -w device)
```

and

```
search=$(adb devices | grep -w ${devicename} | grep -w device)
```

..., but all return the same error.

**How can I get the variable to be interpreted correctly?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you have runs the `adb|grep|grep` pipeline once only and stores the output in `$search`. Reading from `$search` doesn't re-run the pipeline.

Don't use variables to hold commands. Use functions.

```
search() {
    adb devices | grep -w "$devicename" | grep -qw device
}

until search; do
     echo  "Waiting..."
     sleep 10
done
```

Notice that I added `-q` to silence the final grep. You don't need to know what it found, just that it found something. Its exit code is all that matters; its output is irrelevant.

You could inline the function if you want.

```
until adb devices | grep -w "$devicename" | grep -qw device; do
     echo  "Waiting..."
     sleep 10
done
```

Or you could make `$devicename` a parameter, if you wish.

```
search() {
    adb devices | grep -w "$1" | grep -qw device
}

until search "$devicename"; do
     echo  "Waiting..."
     sleep 10
done
```